# Fortran low performance with allocatable arrays

Tags: fortran, allocatable-array

I use Intel Visual Fortran, both IVF2013 and IVF2019. When using allocatable arrays, the program is much slower than the one using static memory allocation. That is to say, if I change from

Method 1: by using fixed array

```
do i = 1, 1000
  call A
end do 

subroutine A
  real(8) :: x(30)
  do things
end subroutine A
```

to something like

Method 2: by using allocatable arrays

```
module module_size_is_defined
  n = 30
end module

do i = 1, 1000
    call A
end do 

subroutine A
  use module_size_is_defined
  real(8), allocatable :: x(:)
  allocate(x(n))
  do things
end subroutine A
```

The code is much slower. For my code, the static allocation takes 1 minutes 30 seconds while the dynamic allocation takes 2 minutes and 30 seconds. Then, I thought is might because that the allocation action was run takes too much time as it is in the loop, then I tried following two methods:

Method 3: by using the module  to allocate the array only once

```
module module_x_is_allocated 
  n = 30
  allocat(x(n))
end module

do i = 1, 1000
  call A
end do 

subroutine A
  use module_x_is_allocated
  do things
end subroutine A
```

Method 4:  by using automatic array

```
module module_size_is_defined
  n = 30
end module


do i = 1, 1000
  call A
end do 

subroutine A
  use module_size_is_defined
  real(x) :: x(n)
  do things
end subroutine A
```

Both Method 3 and Method 4 take almost the same time of the one using dynamic allocated array Method 2. Both around 2 mins 30s. All cases are compiling with same optimization. I tried IVF 2013 and IVF 2019, and same results. I don't know why. Especially for Method 3, although the allocate is only run once, it still takes the same time. It seems that dynamic allocated array is stored at the place that is slower than the static allocated array, and allocation does not take extra time (since method 2 and 3 take the same time).

Any ideas and suggestions that to allocate the arrays in a more efficient manner to reduce the performance penalty? Thanks.

!=========================================================================
**Edit 1:**

My program is too long to post here. Thus, I tried a few small codes. The results are a little bit strange. I tried three cases,

Method 1: takes 28.98s

```
module module_size_is_defined
  implicit none
  integer(4) :: n
end module

program main
  use module_size_is_defined
  implicit none
  
  integer(4) :: i
  real(8) :: y(50,50),z(50,50),t
  
  n = 50
  do i =1,50000
    t=dble(i) * 2.0D0
    call A(y,t)
    z = z + y
  end do
  write(*,*) z(1,1)
end
  
subroutine A(y,t)
  use module_size_is_defined
  implicit none
  real(8),intent(out):: y(n,n)
  real(8),intent(in) :: t
  integer(4) :: j
  real(8) :: x(1,50)
  
  y=0.0D0
  do j = 1, 200
    call getX(x,t,j)
    y = y + matmul( transpose(x) + dble(j)**2, x )
  end do
endsubroutine A
  
  
subroutine getX(x,t,j)
  use module_size_is_defined
  implicit none
  real(8),intent(out) :: x(1,n)
  real(8),intent(in) :: t
  integer(4),intent(in) :: j
  integer(4) :: i
  
  do i =1, n
    x(1,i)  = dble(i+j) * t ** (1.5D00) 
  end do
endsubroutine getX
```

Method 2: takes 30.56s

```
module module_size_is_defined
  implicit none
  integer(4) :: n
end module

program main
  use module_size_is_defined
  implicit none
  
  integer(4) :: i
  real(8) :: y(50,50),z(50,50),t
  
  n = 50
  do i =1,50000
    t=dble(i) * 2.0D0
    call A(y,t)
    z = z + y
  end do
  write(*,*) z(1,1)
end
  
subroutine A(y,t)
  use module_size_is_defined
  implicit none
  real(8),intent(out):: y(n,n)
  real(8),intent(in) :: t
  integer(4) :: j
  real(8),allocatable :: x(:,:)
  allocate(x(1,n))
  
  y=0.0D0
  do j = 1, 200
    call getX(x,t,j)
    y = y + matmul( transpose(x) + dble(j)**2, x )
  end do
endsubroutine A
  
  
subroutine getX(x,t,j)
  use module_size_is_defined
  implicit none
  real(8),intent(out) :: x(1,n)
  real(8),intent(in) :: t
  integer(4),intent(in) :: j
  integer(4) :: i
  
  do i =1, n
    x(1,i)  = dble(i+j) * t ** (1.5D00) 
  end do
endsubroutine getX
```

Method 3: takes 78.72s

```
module module_size_is_defined
  implicit none
  integer(4) :: n
endmodule

module module_array_is_allocated
  use module_size_is_defined
  implicit none
  real(8), allocatable,save :: x(:,:)

  contains
  subroutine init
    implicit none
    allocate(x(1,n))
  endsubroutine
endmodule module_array_is_allocated

program main
  use module_size_is_defined
  use module_array_is_allocated
  implicit none
  
  integer(4) :: i
  real(8) :: y(50,50),z(50,50),t
  
  n = 50
  call init
  do i =1,50000
    t=dble(i) * 2.0D0
    call A(y,t)
    z = z + y
  end do
  write(*,*) z(1,1)
end
  
subroutine A(y,t)
  use module_size_is_defined
  use module_array_is_allocated
  implicit none
  real(8),intent(out):: y(n,n)
  real(8),intent(in) :: t
  integer(4) :: j
  
  y=0.0D0
  do j = 1, 200
    call getX(x,t,j)
    y = y + matmul( transpose(x) + dble(j)**2, x )
  end do
endsubroutine A
  
  
subroutine getX(x,t,j)
  use module_size_is_defined
  implicit none
  real(8),intent(out) :: x(1,n)
  real(8),intent(in) :: t
  integer(4),intent(in) :: j
  integer(4) :: i
  
  do i =1, n
    x(1,i)  = dble(i+j) * t ** (1.5D00) 
  end do
endsubroutine getX
```

Now, with samller size problem, Method 1 and Method 2 is almost same time. But Method 3 should be better than Method 2, since it only allocate x(1,n) once. But it is much slower. **But in my previous program, Method 2 gives almost the same time as Method 3.** It is strange.

I complied in both Windows and Linux, with release setup, -O2 Optimization, with different version of IVF.

Comment: Unless you supply us with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the exact details of how you compiled, linked and ran your code it's very difficult to help.

Comment: How big is the array, how often is the subroutine called? Sometimes automatic arrays are the thing to use, As Ian already wrote, we need the complete code that we can test and measure.

Comment: Your methods 3 and 4 are not valid Fortran, so I would expect those to fail to compile.  Of course, method 2 will be slower.  The locally allocated `x` is automatically deallocated on exit of subroutine `A`.  Thus, you are doing 1000 allocation and deallocations with method 2.  The usual way to solution the problem is to declare `x` in the specification part of the module, have an allocation subroutine called before entering the do-loop and a deallocation subroutine called after the do-loop.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I attached three short codes that can be run directly. It is strange.

Comment: @evets, hi evets, Thanks for comments. I didn't expressed well in the original question. I do declare x in one module and have allocation subroutine before enter the do-loop. Please see my updated question. I included three short codes that can be run directly. I usually use Method 3. But I happened to noticed that Method 1 is much faster. It is strange that the short example shows Method 3 is much slower than Method 2, which should not be that, since Method 2 only need to allocate once. In my project, Method 2 and Method 3 takes almost the same time.

Comment: Looks like you need a better compiler.  My timings for the 3 methods are 11.034 s, 11.707 s, and 11.507 s.  I did lower the main loop from 50000 to 5000 iterations as I don't have the patients to wait too long.

Comment: @evets Thanks evets. I also tried with the main loop to be 5000 iterations. Three methods gives 2.3s, 3.2s and 8.3s.  Could I ask which compiler do you use? I tried IVF2013 in windows, and IVF2019 in Linux with virtual machine. Similar results. In Windows, I use the VS2013+IVF2013 and compile with release mode -O2 Optimization. I feel like allocating within a loop has very little affect on the performance. It might due to how and where the array is stored.

Comment: I use gfortran. Intel compiler is fine.  It comes down to optimizations chosen.  Method 1 is twice as fast as 2 and 3 if I compile with `-O2 -march=native -ftree-vectorize -funroll-loops -fopt-info`.

Comment: @evets Thanks for the details. It seems that now you get the similar performance as I observed in my long program. I really don't understand why method 2 and 3 can have almost same speed.